# How do I retrieve (x) = Arguments from TestNG debug configuration?

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

I am trying to debug a TESTNG test using Debug Configurations option in Eclipse and I need to get the Program arguments inside my TestNG test. Could you please help me in accomplishing it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass values to TestNG via two means in the Run Configurations screen

1. JVM arguments. Below screenshot shows how to pass them

[image: JVM arguments]

1. As environment arguments. Below screenshot shows how to pass them

[image: Environment arguments]

The below sample shows how to read those values from the Run configuration

```java
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class HelloWorldTestClass {

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        //This is how we read values provided via the Environment tab section of the run configuration.
        String environment = System.getenv("env");
        //This is how we read values provided via the VM arguments section 
        String browser = System.getProperty("browser");
        System.err.println("Running on [" + browser + "] in the environment [" + environment + "]");
    }
}
```

Below is the output of the execution:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
Running on [Opera] in the environment [Production]
PASSED: testMethod

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```